# Mount SMB share via javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, smb

Is it possible to mount a smb-share in windows via javascript in a browser on the client side?

I know, implementing this poses a security risk but am mostly interested if this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean in a browser? or, using WSH or even nodejs?

Comment: Ahh sorry, i mean in a browser on the client side.

Comment: then the answer is a definite **no** - usercode in browsers can not, and should not ever, have that sort of access to the operating system

Comment: Ok, i expected something like this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Obviously, no. This would be a major security flaw.

Comment: The only thing you could do is writing some server middleware (doesn't care if its .NET Core, Python, Node or whatever) that access the smb share and execute specific commands like list the directory content and send it to your browser.